# Example of on change, on select, on submit javascript

Tags: javascript

i have an problem of exercises from my school in javascript exercise.

that ask us to give example program of javascript like:

```
on change 
on submit
on select ,
```

on javascript.

i never learn javascript before, i just can php and mysql.

i have tried to learn from googling but i cannt get it because i am blind in javascript.

can someone please help me because of my deathline is almost arrive, arround 2 hour from now.

thank you

Comment: Use `addEventListener` to bind event on an element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

these guys are called "event listeners".

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp

```
<button id="myId" onclick="iAmCalledOnClick()"></button>
```

forms can be submitted:

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="submitMe()"></form>
```

and so on...`submitMe()` and `iAmCalledOnClick()` are functions you need to define in the js side.

i am not 100% sure how to solve it without jquery, but i think this would also work:

```
document.getElementById("myId").addEventListener("onclick", iAmCalledOnClick());
```

http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-vs-raw-javascript-3-events-ajax/

greetings